# How to explicitly move the cursor in python

Tags: python

I wanted to know if there was any way I could print a set of lines in Python and then move the cursor up or down to different locations. For example,

Output:

First Name         Last Name 

Email Address

Password

If I printed the above lines, how would I able to move the cursor from after password to where it would usually be to, just after First Name so that the user could enter raw input to be stored in a specific variable.

Comment: You mean move cursor in cmd?

Comment: On what system are you?  I can  provide an answer for Unix systems. Linux/ MacOS

Comment: yes cmd while executing a scripted program... I'm on Windows :/

Comment: could u give me the answer on unix? i'll see if i can find a way to adapt it to windows

Comment: No,  as the blessings library only works on Unix systems.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Using the blessings library you could use this on unix systems:

```
from blessings import Terminal

t = Terminal()

with t.fullscreen():
    print('First Name:')
    print('Last Name:')
    print('Age:')

    firstname = input(t.move(0, 14))
    lastname = input(t.move(1, 14))
    age = input(t.move(2, 14))
```